# How to make redirect if HTML-document doesn't exist on server

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, ssi, server-side-includes

How to make redirect to 404 or root page when user types query to not existing page and SSI include gets error?

Or how to check if HTML-document exist on server and if doesn't then also make redirect?

If user types `domain.tld?anyquerystring`on my site then it includes `anyquerystring.html` HTML-page by SSI.

If user types query of not existing page like `domain.tld?blahblahblah` then it gives the `[an error occurred while processing this directive]` in the place of SSI include.

Comment: look at file_exists() http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Thought this was a querystring issue include($_GET['page']); But .htaccess -f (file not exist) and -d (directory not exist) with apache's mod_rewrite will do the trick

Comment: Why are you talking about SSI in a question tagged PHP? Are you using PHP or SSI? What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: Because I don't what could help here from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure error message in SSI. The answer is

```
<!--#config errmsg="Put here your error message, HTML or other code" -->
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to check it with php, because if a page does not exists how your php code can run, you need to make changes to .htaccess file as it will tell the server to a redirect a user to a defined page in case of 404

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

Comment: You didn't read the question. I'm not getting 404 I'm getting error in the place of SSI include that's included into another page.